# App Name has already been used?

Tags: ios, error-handling, app-store-connect

So in my case this is very odd. I have 2 individual iTC accounts (don't ask why), anyway my old account had this name as an App and then it expired with the name still taken by that dormant account.

Now on my new account, I am trying to use that name so I had to go through the process of calling Apple Developer Support and finally I regained access to that old account and deleted the app completely that had the name.

So now I have waited over 48 Hours and on the current account I am using, I am trying to use that app name since like I said, it is deleted. But the thing is, it still says 'App name has already been used'.

I am very confused about why. This app was never in the App Store, just in testing stages but I fully deleted the app on the old account. Does anyone have any idea why the name is still taken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you created an entry for the first App in iTunesConnect, even if it was never submitted or uploaded, then that name is locked to that iTunesConnect App permanently.

From the [Apple App Store Submission Tips](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html)

> The name you select for your app is perhaps one of the most important
>   aspects to marketing your app and can distinguish your app on the App
>   Store. Here are a few things to keep in mind when naming your app or
>   changing the name of your app.
>
> - Changing the Name of Your App. You can change the name of your existing app only when submitting an update of your app binary. *If you
>     submit an app name which is already in use within the same geography
>     in which your app is sold, you will be prompted to enter another name.*

More good info here [iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf).

All the dev forums/docs I can find say the same thing, if you have ever used that App Name before, then that name is locked permanently.

Comment: Ok so the first version will have to be something different, then when I update it for the first time, I can change it back to the original name, correct?

Comment: You _might_ be able to do that, but I don't know that the name will ever be available again even though it was deleted from the old account.  Trying to change the name with an update is probably the best option though.

Comment: doesn't the name free up 90 days after or something like that?

Comment: I remember that I originally got the app name to the old account from my account because I deleted it on the new account and it was still available on the old account so I am not sure why it doesn't work vice versa for the second time.

Comment: Oh, good point.  There is a 120 day expiration period where the App will be removed from iTunesConnect if a binary is not uploaded after 120 days.  So at worst, you will have to wait 4 months =/, but that's better then never!

Comment: True, anyway I will contact Apple Developer Support again just to make sure, because when I talked to the engineering department for high level requests, they assured me that they would be able to migrate it over, but we'll see!

Comment: @iBradApps: Would you mind telling what they replied?

Comment: @JustKidding I believe that the app name is locked in for 90 days on one account. After that you can use it on another account without any issues. I don't think that first account can use the name ever again though even after the 90 days. It's been long since I was faced with this issue though.