# App name not available in iTunes

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

In iTunes i have created one app with the name. And after that I have edited the name before uploading the build. Now I have tried to revert back to the previous name whice I entered first. But Now I am getting the message "The App Name you entered has already been used.". Please help me to get back my old app name.

Thanks, Jasmine.

Comment: This answer may provide the answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7700254/184245

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Since you have used this name in the past this name is locked and you cannot use it again. Strangely, it doesn't matter that it is for the same app.
If I were you I would try contacting apple and explain the situation.

Comment: @Jasmine Do you need any further information? I would be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my App's name and reverted back to the previous name, it worked for me. Unfortunately in your case when you edited your app's name your last name must be taken by some other developer. Because I tried to reproduce this condition.

I have **2 iTunes connect**:

**Case 1:**

1) I created an App with name 'X' on my first iTunes Connect account

2) edited the same app as name 'XYZ'

3) reverted back to 'X', it worked

**Case 2:**

1) Tried to create an App with name 'X' on my second iTunes Connect account, gave me an error name already taken

2) Edited my app to "XYZ" on first iTunes connect account

3) Tried to create app with 'X' on second iTunes connect account, it allowed me to create app now

4) Tried to revert back app's name to 'X' on First iTunes Connect account, it gave me an error that app name is already taken