# Unable to upload app in app store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I made iPhone app,

Now i want to upload my app on the app store, few days before i deleted my same app from app store, and i have created new app with same name and when i try to upload my new app in `iTunesConnect` it shows,

**ERROR:**

`The App Name you entered has already been used.` even i have deleted my App from the store.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699869/app-name-has-already-been-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use the same bundleID as you did for the other app. If the bundleIDs are different then the system thinks you are trying to upload a different app with the same name.

Of course, if you deleted the app completely, then this won't help.

Comment: I have created new project in Xcode, and unable to `EDIT` `bundleID`

Comment: The bundle identifier should be editable. That's the one that is usually com.yourcompany.appname

Answer (score 2):

As per the iTunes Connect Developer Guide we can not use same app name once we used it in same account even if we delete the old app.
You can get more information regarding this from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html), under

**Managing Your App
   |-> Deleting an App section**

Here is one Important Note from this guideline.

[image]