# AppStoreConnect - app name still unavailable after 2 days since it became free

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

So we had an unreleased app in one account, and decided to release it on another. First I renamed the app in the first account so that name becomes free, and then deleted it altogether. However I still get this error (2 days have passed) when trying to set a new app name (which is already free):

*English (U.S.) Name couldn’t be saved because the app name you entered is already being used. If you have trademark rights to this name and would like it released for your use, submit a claim.*

New name in other localizations in successfully saved, but not in default language. Any workaround to this?
Or the name is still cached and we need to wait some more?

Comment: I think you may need to transfert the app from one account to another. (Do not do if you are in Small Business as you could loose Small Business)

Comment: We already deleted app in the old account.

Comment: Did you tried to see if you can add again the app on the old account ? if so you could then move it to new account.

Comment: Did you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699869/app-name-has-already-been-used?rq=1) : quite old but may be still valid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dealing with the App Store is not programming and is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should've transferred the app to the new account.
Anyway call apple customer support to fix this issue.